# How to display data from master view into detail view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to Ios programming i want to display the data from master view controller into the detail view controller, i am using the master detail template from xcode. the detail array is working it shows the detail in label, how ever i want to display the title as well which is stored in _objects array,

here is my code

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_detailObjects;
    NSMutableArray *_thumbnailImage;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController
@synthesize _objects;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title= @"Zodiac List";

    _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                @"value 1",
                @"value 2",
                @"value 3",
                @"value 4",
                @"value 5",
              ,nil];
    _detailObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                      @"detail of value 1",
                      @"detail of value 2",
                      @"detail of value 3",
                      @"detail of value 4",
                      @"detail of value 5",
                      , nil];
   }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSMutableArray *object = _detailObjects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}

@end
```

the detail is working fine how ever i want to display the value 1, value 2,value 2 in a label as well.. 
here is my detail view controller code..

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItemTitle;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *zodiacNameLabel;
```

here is .m file code

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize zodiacNameLabel;


#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

-(void) setDetailItemTitle:(id)detailItemTitle{
    if (_detailItemTitle !=detailItemTitle) {
        _detailItemTitle = detailItemTitle;

        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
      //  self.zodiacNameLabel.text = [self.]

            MasterViewController *master = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
            zodiacNameLabel.text = [master._objects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

//    if (self.detailItemTitle) {
//        self.zodiacNameLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
//    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];

//    MasterViewController *master = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
//    zodiacNameLabel.text = [master._objects objectAtIndex:0];

//    MasterViewController *master = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];
//    zodiacNameLabel.text = [master._objects objectAtIndex:0]; // you can get first element of an array

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong - in convention you don't do `@synthesize _objects;`. Your initial property will just be `object` and when you synthesize it you do `@synthesize object = _object;` and are we meant to know what `_object` is? Please share all you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `delegate` method of `tableview` which is in your `masterviewcontroller` and then inside that push your data whatever you want to display in `masterviewcontroller` like that:-

Assuming that below delegate is in your `masterViewController`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      _yourController = [[yourController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

      [self.navigationController pushViewController:_yourController animated:YES];

    }
```

Now this will `alloc`, `initialize` and `load` your `nib` into `detailviewcontroller` and if you  want to send message from master to detail then declare `property` method in `detailviewcontroller` and just pass it from above like that below:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      _yourDetailController = [[yourDetailController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourDetailController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            [_yourDetailController setTempString:@"test"]; //Assuming that tempString is declared in yourDetailController class
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:_yourDetailController animated:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array that is "tmpArray" in detailViewController and then you can copied _objects array in to tmpArray. like this

MastrerViewController.m

```
DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
detail.tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:_objects];
```

DetailViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *tmpArray;
```